# SciPy skewnormal fitting

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit data into a skew normal distribution using the *SciPy Skewnorm* package.

However, I am failing to understand the usage properly as I cannot find proper documentation or examples on this matter.

On the help section I found [Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html) and trying to use `skewnorm.fit()` along with `skewnorm.pdf()` to fit data into a model and use that model to output a distribution and compare with the original data.

Please let me know if anyone can help with this.

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# choose some parameters
a, loc, scale = 5.3, -0.1, 2.2
# draw a sample
data = stats.skewnorm(a, loc, scale).rvs(1000)
# estimate parameters from sample
ae, loce, scalee = stats.skewnorm.fit(data)
# Plot the PDF.
plt.figure()
plt.hist(data, bins=100, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = stats.skewnorm.pdf(x,ae, loce, scalee)#.rvs(100)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you are looking at the `fit()` method, then you are modeling your data as random samples drawn from a skew-normal distribution, and you want to estimate the parameters of that distribution.  Is that correct?  If so, have you tried something as simple as `params = skewnorm.fit(data)`, where `data` is a 1-d array or sequence that contains your input values?  (See Paul Panzer's answer for an example.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @WarrenWeckesser, your assumption is correct. I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: It worked and I updated the post @warren-weckesser. Unfortunately I cannot use photos yet!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example to get you started.

```
>>> from scipy import stats

# choose some parameters
>>> a, loc, scale = 1.3, -0.1, 2.2
# draw a sample
>>> sample = stats.skewnorm(a, loc, scale).rvs(1000)

# estimate parameters from sample
>>> ae, loce, scalee = stats.skewnorm.fit(sample)
>>> ae
1.2495366661560348
>>> loce
-0.039775813819310835
>>> scalee
2.1126121580965536
```

Comment: Thanks for your example code @paulpanzer I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that there is an analytical solution but I just pulled an all night coding a solution to this problem with a genetic algorithm. I'm not familiar with genetic algorithms, so I sort of just based it off intuition - accordingly, I think this code manages to sit in the intersection of both being moderately intelligent work, and profoundly dumb lmfao. I'll put push it to GitHub if anyone might find it useful. Pic related - converging on decent distribution fit. Given mode and upper and lower 95% confidence interval bounds.

[image]

Comment: Please review [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and note well that this is not a discussion forum. The answer section is only for attempts at actually answering the question. An answer needs to stand on its own, because users in five years shouldn't have to contact you for the details. Please [edit] your answer to include the details of the solution.