# How to fit a mixed model with a skew normal distribution in python?

Tags: python, distribution, normal-distribution, mixed-models, skew

I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this so if not, please let me know,

however I am using `StatsModels` to create a mixed effects model that assesses the relationship between a factored predictor and continuous dependent variable, taking into account group effects.

```
model = smf.mixedlm("continuous_dv ~ factored_predictor", df, groups=df['group'])
```

The challenge is that the underlying data has a skewed normal distribution, and I am not sure how to fit a mixed model with that distribution in Python?

In R there is a package `skewlmm` which allows for this, and I am wondering what the counterpart would be in Python (if it exists?).

I have seen the following links

[SciPy skewnormal fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140371/scipy-skewnormal-fitting)

and similar which show how to fit data INTO a skew normal distribution by using `skewnormfit()`

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check `scipy.stats.skewnorm`? Why does it not work for you?

Comment: I have, and my understanding of it (which albeit could be very wrong) is that I can fit my data using it and generate predictions, however, I am trying to obtain the mixed model output so I can also see group effects. This however could be because I am confused on how to implement skewnorm and integrate the output with a mixed model.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what do you expect when you say "mixed model output"?

Comment: Ah yes, apologies. Model metrics, coefficients, p-values, confidence intervals, etc.

Comment: My bad, I misread your question. Just saw the model-fitting part, thought you were just aiming for a skewed distribution. I don't think `statsmodels` can handle that indeed. I'd ask in Cross Validated.

Comment: No worries and thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is some potential with this - a Python interface for the R package `brms` which can fit Bayesian mixed effects models with a skew normal distribution (and more).

https://github.com/adamhaber/pybrms

Comment: Good idea, but please see my answer, as it might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> The challenge is that the underlying data has a skewed normal distribution, and I am not sure how to fit a mixed model with that distribution in Python?

The distribution of the data is not a concern.

There is no requirement for the response variable itself to be normally distributed in a linear mixed model (LMM). It is the distribution of the response, conditional on the random effects, that is assumed to be normally distributed. This means that the residuals should be (approximately) normally distributed. Therefore, you can proceed with fitting an LMM and then check the residuals to see if they are normally distributed.

---

Edit:

If you find that you actually do need do need to hande skewed residuals, then this can sometimes be achieved by transforming the data, or fitting a GLMM. If all that fails then your self-answer, about using the python interface for the the R `brms` package, `pybrms` is a very good one.